# windows findstr match specific numeric

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have an xml file that has values resembling this:

```
  <Editable default="XXX07770004183" description="Station Id" name="MachineID.PSID" regex="^XXX[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}$"/>

  <Editable default="17" description="Machine Number" name="MachineID.MachineID" regex="^[0-9]+$"/>

  <Editable default="32" description="Asset number" name="MachineID.AssetNumber" regex="^[0-9]+$"/>

  <Editable default="AAALLL74" description="Serial number" name="MachineID.SerialNumber" regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"/>
```

I'd like to get the value of asset number (32 in this example) and save it to a variable. The asset number can be 5 digits in length.

This is Windows batch with findstr.

findstr /C:MachineID.AssetNumber Static.Settings.xml but this only matches the entire line:

```
<Editable default="32" description="Asset number of the machine." name="MachineID.AssetNumber" regex="^[0-9]+$"/>
```

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `for /f` loop to "disassemble" a line:

```
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%a in ('findstr /C:"MachineID.AssetNumber" Static.Settings.xml') do set asset=%%a
echo %asset%
```

The strange syntax instead of `"tokens=2 delims=""` is neccessary to correctly process the quote.

Comment: That's perfect! Gave me exactly what I needed: 32